# Why is my Angular code returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was playing around with angular to geo locate the address of the client using angular and some API services. I have gotten it to correctly locate the IP address but for some reason I haven't been able to perform a geo lookup. The API service is running fine and my URL seems to be good too.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Zeus', [])
.controller('ZeusController', function ($scope, $http) {

    function fetchIP() {
        $http.get("http://ipv4.myexternalip.com/json")
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.ip = response.data.ip;
            });
        return $scope.ip
    }

    var ip = String(fetchIP());

    function geoIP() {
            $http.get("https://freegeoip.net/json/" + String(ip))
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.country_code = response.data.country_code;
                });
        return $scope.country_code;
    }

    var latLon = geoIP();


});
```

I get the following error in my Chrome console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)
https://freegeoip.net/json/undefined
```

The URL should definitely not be undefined because using the IP that angular returns the url returns the correct response in the web browser.

Comment: bro can u share the html as well coz i am getting this error 
GET https://freegeoip.net/json/undefined 404 ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `geoIP()` has callback and you have to handle that callback

Like this

```
function geoIP() {
    return $http.get("https://freegeoip.net/json/" + String(ip))
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data.country_code;
        });

}
var latLon;
geoIP().then(function(r) {
    latLon = r;
})
```